# How do I use the user agent default stylesheet on another element?

Tags: html, css

Every user agent has its own default stylesheet. For example here is the default `button` element style for the current Edge Chromium:

```
button {
    appearance: auto;
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: -internal-light-dark(black, white);
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(239, 239, 239), rgb(59, 59, 59));
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133));
    border-image: initial;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

I'd like to make an anchor element look like a button. I could copy the CSS above in a `a` selector but that would make the anchor look like an Edge Chromium button on every browser.

How do I copy the current browser's default appearance of an element, and apply it to another?

Comment: other than rewriting the style manually, I don't think there is another solution

Comment: Anyone figured out how to do this in CSS yet?

Answer (score 1):

I would retrieve the style information of the specific element that you want to copy, and apply that style to the desired element using javascript.

You can retrieve the css information using the `getComputedStyle` method.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('buttonID');
 
const styles = window.getComputedStyle(btn);
```

You can read more on this [page](https://attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-get-css-styles)

Comment: How do I apply styles after having retrieved them?

Comment: What about via CSS?